# QGIS: show attributes of different colums in legend

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, expression, legend

I'd need to classify and display on a map different land cover symbols by its Corine Land Cover codes, but in the meanwhile I'd like to show them in legend as symbol (based on UDSCOD) + code (UDSCOD) + description (UDSDESC)?

This is what I get:

[image]

That is an example of what I'd like to get: [image]:
[image]

Comment: You could create an additional field that aggregates what you want, and use that field to classify your data.

Answer (score 5):

**In the layout you have to deactivate auto update:**

[image]

**Next you have to edit the expression:**

[image]

[image]

```
@symbol_label + ' ' + aggregate(@layer, 'concatenate_unique', "label", filter:="code"=@symbol_label)
```

"code" fieldname  you have categorized your symbol. "label" is the fieldname you want to add